# Help Antie evaluate Gauss curvature of a smooth surface using ruler and a protractor

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Antie, a smart ant living on a smooth surface $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, would like to evaluate the Gauss curvature $K$ at a certain point $P\in S$. Antie is aware of Gauss Theorema Egregium, according to which Gauss curvature may be evaluated using the first fundamental form of the surface. So, Antie grabs a ruler and a  protractor, determines a neighbourhood  around $P$ and is ready to start calculating, since it has heard that the first fundamental form is related to lengths and angles around $P$ (words like tangent space do not really make sense to Antie). Αntie knows that if he knew some quantities, called $E$, $F$, $G$, then it would be able to evaluate $K$.

But of course Antie is not aware of the way the surface is embedded in space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its local parametrization $\sigma(u,v)=( \sigma_1(u,v),   \sigma_2(u,v),\sigma_3(u,v))$ around $P$ (in order to evaluate $E=\sigma_u\cdot \sigma_u$ etc around $P$).

How would we help Antie calculate all the quantities needed for Gauss curvature $K$ at $P$?

Comment: I think you'll find that a hard sell with other MSE users... there are 3 things required of a question here: 1) clear problem statement 2) context for the problem 3) your own working on the problem (not including measures taken in step 1)). Your question has yet to meet requirements 2) and 3)

Comment: (Just to note, if you weren't able to get anywhere with this question by yourself, that's fine too - as long as you can clearly explain which part(s) you don't understand and why!)

Comment: The thing is, one cannot compute general smooth functions using the compass and ruler (one cannot even compute cube roots of real numbers). One can only approximate their values. Maybe it is good enough for her.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "context of the problem"? Isn't it obvious that one wants to evaluate, at least approximate,   Gauss curvature at a point by means of compass and ruler only? (if possible).

Comment: By context I mean: what is the source? It a homework question? An assigned question from a book? A contest question such as the IMO? Or did you come up with it yourself? Where, if anywhere, can an interested party go to read the question or materials related to it?

Comment: You mean that in order to be a well posed question it needs to have a reference? The content alone (for the specific question, not generally speaking) is not enough for someone to get all the needed information? Note that it is a solid question (maybe not so rigorous, but that was the intention, anyway). In any case, if you have something that could add some light to the question, you may add it as an answer.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Keep in mind that the goal of this website is to create a repository of questions and answers.  The question you ask should be useful not just to you, but also to future readers.  This includes adding context, such as a reference to the source of the problem, or some discussion of the *motivation* behind the problem.  As I read it right now, your question essentially boils down to "how is curvature computed using only intrinsic properties of a manifold?", along with a bunch of obfuscatory fluff.  I think that the question is interesting (as a mathematical problem), but...

Comment: ...I do not think that it is a very good fit for the Q&A format expected on this site.  I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with the [context standards](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) that questions on this site are expected to meet.

Comment: @Xander Henderson, I must admit that I am surprised by your answer, which I didn't expect based on your experience here. Of course the question boils down to your remark, but what exactly makes the frame not appropriate for future readers? It is a well posed question, driven by my own research on the topic and  since I guess has a quite standard answer for an expert (I suppose), does not need to have a reference on a paper etc (as so many other questions on this page). If you like, please contribute with an answer (and question if you prefer) that will help also future readers.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout (1) I am not in the habit of answering questions which I don't think are a good fit for the site, and (2) I work in the general area of fractal geometry and analysis on fractals---what do I know about curvature?  In any event, you asked about why someone might downvote the question, or why someone might not consider it a good fit.   I cannot possibly know who downvoted or why, but I can explain why I don't think that the question, as phrased, is a great fit for the site.

Comment: @Xander Henderson, since i an not fond of guessing, i can not answer your question about your knowledge on curvature. Anyway,  your opposition is noted for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: the “ruler and protractor” has the following functions:

Ruler: draw a geodesic between two points, and measure the length of that geodesic

Protractor: given two geodesics intersecting at a point P, measure the angle they make at point P.

At least on the plane, these are the correct properties of the ruler and the protractor. I don’t know if they are the correct properties of these instruments on the surface.

I don't know a lot of differential geometry, but here might be a feasible approach.

Draw a sufficiently small geodesic right triangle $ABC$ around $P$, say with angle $B$ being 90 degrees and $AB = BC$, and (very accurately) measure the angles $\angle ABC, \angle ACB, \angle BAC$. By Gauss-Bonet, we have
$$\int_{\triangle ABC} K dA = \angle ABC + \angle ACB + \angle BAC - \pi.$$
Now, if $K_P$ is the curvature at point $P$,  we have
$$\int_{\triangle ABC} K dA = (1 + o(1)) \text{Area}(\triangle ABC) \cdot K_P$$
and
$$\text{Area}(\triangle ABC) = \frac{1 + o(1)}{2} AB \cdot BC.$$
So, as the triangle's area converges to $0$, we have
$$K_P \sim \frac{2(\angle ABC + \angle ACB + \angle BAC - \pi)}{AB \cdot BC}.$$
The ant can measure all the quantities on the right hand side, so by taking sufficiently small triangles, can measure $K_P$ with arbitrary accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. So is the following statement true? "Theorema Egregium  guarantees that Gauss curvature is intrinsic to the surface, by expressing it in terms of the first fundamental form (especially in E,F,G in local parameters). But since a two-dimensional resident of the surface cannot evaluate E,F,G (since they refer to the way surface is embedded in space), one way to practically evaluate $K$ is using Gauss Bonnet (as so clearly stated)."

Comment: Alas, it is totally unclear how to compute ratios of angles to areas using the compass and ruler (especially on a surface which is not locally flat).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think the author's problem asks us to use a ruler and a protractor, which is an instrument that measures angles.

Comment: But I still know very little about the subject, so I am happy to be corrected on this.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout I don't know enough about E,F,G to answer that question.

Comment: How do you know what curves will be the sides of your triangle? The OP does not know how to find geodesics in his space. You were sloppy in your statement and forgot to specify that this must be a triangle whose edges are geodesics. @Nikolaos You need $E,F,G$ as functions of parameters and you need their first and second derivatives everywhere nearby. This information is not accessible "with ruler and compass."

Comment: I made the assumption that the ruler is able to draw geodesic between two points( since I guess this is what a ruler should do?) let me know if you have an alternate interpretation of what the ruler does.